# JS - ¿alternativa a return false?

Tags: javascript

Mas que una pregunta, es una cuestión que quiero leer de los que llevais mucho tiempo dandoos de cabezazos con esto.

Estoy en JavaScript, estoy haciendo un validador de formulario y me veo en la situación que quiero cortar por completo llegado un momento si los datos que llegan no son correctos.

Tengo entendido que meter en mitad de una función un return no es muy buena idea. Pero ahora estoy con la duda de como hacerlo. Y tengo esa duda siempre.

¿Alguien podría decirme la alternativa (práctica, teórica, lo que sea) de usar RETURN FALSE para terminar con la ejecución de una funcion? (Sin tener que usar condicionales claro). ¿Y porque sería mejor?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Hola Jose. Tu pregunta no está clara del todo. Puedes explicar mejor la traza de tu programa y donde y cuando quieres pararla? Respecto a decirte alternativas y *"cual seria mejor"*, eso se considera basado en opiniones. Debes investigar tu las opciones que haya y tratar de implementarlo. Si en el proceso tienes errores o dudas concretas, preguntar aqui. Cuando tengas 20 de rep podrás participar en el [chat] y preguntar por opiniones sin problema. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias lois6b, realmente no es en un programa si no en varios. Me estoy fijando que tengo demasiadas funciones que llegan a tener muchos "return false" en medio de condicionales y no se si es buena idea. Por eso preguntaba, mas que por un caso concreto. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tengo entendido que meter en mitad de una función un return no es muy
>   buena idea

Es una recomendación para que el código sea más legible, se la llama "punto único de salida" ([*single exit point*](https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/coding-tips/coding-tip-have-a-single-exit-point/)). Por ejemplo, si modificas una función y haces cambio, puede ser que el cambio

Por ejemplo, ahora mismo he depurado una función de inicialización y, si el valor de la configuración era `null`, hacía un `return null;` en medio del código porque no había que hacer nada. Después añadí más código de inicialización que se tenía que ejecutar siempre y me dejé el `return`.

También puede afectar a la facilidad de depuración.

Las alternativa más sencilla es cambiar el flujo para que la comprobación implique la ejecución,  es decir de:

```
function hola() {
   if (valor == 0) {
     return false;
   }
   // Hacer hola();
   return loquetoque;
}
```

pasa a :

```
function hola() {
   if (valor != 0) {
      // hacer hola();
      return loquetoque;
   }
   return false;
}
```

o variedades similares (poner el `return false` en un `else`, poner el valor a devolver en una variable y solo hacer un `return`, etc.)

En todo caso, lo primero es la claridad del código, no es una regla que deba seguirse ciegamente. En concreto, hacer una serie de `return` al principio del código según comprobaciones de parámetros puede ser una idea mejor.

```
function hola(par1, par2, par3, par4) {
   if (par1 == 0) {
      return false;
   }
   if ((par2 == 1) && (par4 ==5)) {
      return false;
   }
   if (par3 == 2) {
      return false;
   }
   return loquetoque;
   // hacer hola
}
```

antes que:

```
function hola(par1, par2, par3, par4) {
   if ((par1 != 0) || ((par2 != 1) && (par4 != 5)) || (par3 != 1) {
      // hacer hola
      return loquetoque;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: Me gusta mucho el comentario indicado. Ademas, el concepto de un unico punto de salida me lo ha hecho ver de manera clara.